# How to load data in in-memory database from other (Postgres) database?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I want to load the data from a table in Postgres database to in-memory H2 database. Do we have such feature in H2 (or any other) in-memory database? I am using spring boot and hibernate.

> Why I want to do this

For our application, we need fast retrieval time so we will be using the in-memory database as a cache and avoid database trip for every API call. We will load the cache from actual postgres database on application startup and then subsequently every API call will read the data from cache. We will be refreshing the cache periodically from the postgres database.

Comment: Its is possible using multiple datasources but why you wanna do that? I would suggest keep your dev data separate from test/prod data. Dont mix them..please. You can avoid complexity too if you dont mix them.

Comment: @AjayKumar updated the question (it's not about dev/prod environments).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [linked table](https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#create_linked_table) in H2 database

```sql
CREATE LINKED TABLE EXTERNAL_TABLE_NAME('',
    'jdbc:postgressql:…', 'user', 'password', 'tableNameInPostgreSQL');
```

You can work with this linked table directly, but all operations will be redirected to the PostgreSQL and can be relatively slow.

If you wish you can create a normal table in H2 with a copy of data from the linked table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE OWN_TABLE_NAME AS TABLE EXTERNAL_TABLE_NAME;
```

After that the linked table isn't needed any more and can be dropped:

```
DROP TABLE EXTERNAL_TABLE_NAME;
```

This command will drop only the link, the real table in the PostgreSQL's database will not be dropped.